# How to display the GUI Extension Button only for Folder operations?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I have created a GUI button, and i would like to enable the button when the user selects any folder only.

I have tried to give the config xml like below, but its displaying always.

```
          <ext:apply>                
            <ext:view name="DashboardView">
              <ext:control id="DashboardToolbar"/>
            </ext:view>
              <ext:view name="FolderView">
                  <ext:control id="ItemToolbar"/>
              </ext:view>

          </ext:apply>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to implement the `isEnabled` method in the `Command` interface with the following check, to make sure that the type of the selected element is FOLDER.

```
YourEditor.YourCommand.prototype.isEnabled = 
            function YourCommand$isEnabled(selection) {
    var itemID = selection.getItem(0);

    if ($models.getItemType(itemID) != $const.ItemType.FOLDER) {
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;   
};
```

- If you return `true` on the `isEnabled` function, the button will be enabled.
- If you return `false`, the button will be disabled

If you need further information on how to setup the extension you can refer to:

- https://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/GUIextensionIn8steps.aspx

Comment: return ($models.getItemType(itemID) == $const.ItemType.FOLDER);

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "FolderView". Think of a View in Tridion's GUI as a screen. So you have the DashboardView that has a tree on the left and a list on the right, then there's a Component view that pops up when you Open a Component, etc.

Given your requirement, you're adding a button to the DashboardView and want it to enable/disable based on the selection. You will have to implement that logic in the `isEnabled` method of your command's JavaScript.

If you look at any of the existing extensions out there, you will see that a `selection` parameter is passed into this method. You can determine which items (and thus their type) from that and thus determine when to enable/disable your button.